# Attach term to solution of PDE(perturbation theory)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Currently I am struggeling with the following problem: Actually I have a found a solution to the PDE $\Delta \Phi(r,\theta)=f(r,\theta)$ and now I want to include a small extra term given by $kg(r)\Phi(r,\theta)$ a priori to the differential equation where $g(r)=1$, if $|r|>R\in \mathbb{R}$ so "outside a sphere" and g(r)=0 inside the sphere. Is there any way to approximatively attach this behavior to the solution to the differential equation a posteriori or do you see any other chance to do this approximatively?

It might be worth saying that the solution of the differential equation is rather a complicated function. Since I do not want to busy you with the full calculation I was just wondering whether you know some equations(maybe perturbation theory) in order to do this right.

Comment: What do you mean by attach?